# Magento how to add bundle item images and quantity for each bundle item?

Tags: php, magento

I have made a bundle product in which i want to add only one image per bundle and also add quantity increase/decrease for each bundle item.

i have tried with check-box  like this

```
 <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_selection, 'small_image')->resize(200,200); ?>" />
```

it works well but i am getting each item image instead of one image

2nd i have put a span of quantity add which doesn't work

```
 <span class="qty-holder">
            <label for="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?>&nbsp;</label>
<input onkeyup="bundle.changeSelectionQty(this, event)" onblur="bundle.changeSelectionQty(this, event)" <?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?> id="bundle-option-<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>-qty-input" class="input-text qty<?php if (!$_canChangeQty) echo ' qty-disabled' ?>" type="text" name="bundle_option_qty[<?php echo $_option->getId() ?>]" value="<?php echo $_defaultQty ?>"/>

       </span>
```

I want a bundle product something like following link:
http://www.thewhitecompany.com/bedroom/bed-linen/genoa-bed-linen-collection--silver/